# C++ input file string to float error

Tags: c++

So the example is what I want to get from my function, but I can't get atof to work because I keep getting " error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double atof(const char*)’". Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Invoice2.txt:

```
hammer#9.95
saw#20.15
shovel#35.40
```

Program:

```
/* EXAMPLES:    *** Invoice ***
        ---------------------------- 
        hammer                $9.95

        saw                  $20.15

        shovel               $35.40
        ---------------------------- 
         3 items:           $65.50
*/


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// Accepts: N/A
// Returns: 0 if no error

int main(void){
    int totalItems, position;
    double totalPrice, price;
    string line, name;
    ifstream inputFile("invoice2.txt");
    cout << "*** Invoice ***" << endl << "----------------------------" <<
        endl;
    totalItems = 0;
    do{ 
        position = line.find('#');
        name = line.substr(0, position);
        price = atof(line.substr(position+1, line.length()));
        cout << name << "\t\t\t$" << price << endl;
        totalItems += 1;
        totalPrice += price;
    } while (getline(inputFile, line));
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "  " << totalItems << ":\t\t\t$" << totalPrice << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atof` requires a pointer to a `const char`, and you give it a `string`. In order to make it work, you have to convert a string to a char table using the `c_str()` method on it.

Comment: I also have a blank line coming in at the start of my table. Any clue of why that is happening?

Comment: I'm guessing you got a blank line in your file

Comment: I do not, I checked just to make sure. Could it have something to do with getline? It prints a blank "name" and then $0

Comment: The way you have structured your loop you perform work before reading anything from the file.  Change it to a `while(getline(...))` loop so you read first then do the work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja My professor said that I specifically needed a do while loop :/

Comment: Well, you have a bad professor then. :)  You could add an `if(!line.empty())` check I suppose although changing the loop is a more proper solution.